# Conditionally enumerating items in python

Tags: python, iterable

I'd like to enumerate those items in an iterable that satisfy a certain condition. I've tried something like

```
[(i,j) for i,j in enumerate(range(10)) if (3 < j) and (j < 8)]
```

(that tries to enumerate the numbers between 4 and 7 just for the sake of an example). From this, I get the result

```
[(4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7)]
```

What I'd like to get is

```
[(0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7)]
```

Is there a pythonic way to achieve the desired result?

Note that in the actual problem I'm working on, I don't know in advance how many items satisfy the condition.

Comment: Btw, you can write `3 < j < 8`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do the enumerate last so the indexes start from 0.

```
enumerate(j for j in range(10) if (3 < j) and (j < 8))
```

If you need the list rather than enumerate object, just wrap this all in `list()`

Answer (score 4):

You can do the filtering in a generator, then do the enumeration on the result of that expression afterwards.

```
>>> [(index,value) for index,value in enumerate(j for j in range(10) if (3 < j) and (j < 8))]
[(0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7)]
```

Or equivalently `enumerate` will yield tuples of `(index, value)` already so you can use

```
>>> list(enumerate(j for j in range(10) if (3 < j) and (j < 8)))
[(0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7)]
```

Comment: I see you have double parenthesis after the enumerate keyword in both examples, why?..I've tried it without the double parenthesis and it worked fine...

Comment: @KhalilAmmour You can drop the parentheses. I had `[]` before because I initially used a list comprehension, then switched to `()` to make it a generator expression, but then after adding `enumerate` forgot to drop the inner set of parentheses. They are superfluous, you can remove them.

Answer (score 2):

#### Why you are wrong: you get the result then filter it.

`[(i,j) for i,j in enumerate(range(10))]` will get `[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9)]`, then you use `if (3 < j) and (j < 8)`(j is the second item in the tuple), so the result would be `[(4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7)]`

#### What you should do: filter the sequence passed to `range()` first.

it means: for example, you want to enumerate the numbers between 4 and 7, so you should do the filtering first

```
>>> [j for j in range(10) if 3 < j < 8]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
```

then you pass it to `enumerate`:

```
>>> list(enumerate([4, 5, 6, 7]))
[(0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7)]
```

so, the solution should be:

```
>>> list(enumerate(i for in range(10) if 3 < i < 8))
[(0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7)]
```

In a word, just remember to **do the filtering first**.

Comment: See my edit. There was another answer, now apparently deleted, that had the same issue.

Comment: @silvado Ah, when I answer the question you haven't edited it yet, so I misunderstood it. I've edited my answer, hope it helps.